# Where to add C wire on this air handler?

Tags: thermostat, thermostat-c-wire

Thanks for helping me here.  I am adding a new wifi thermostat to my system but need to add a C wire directly to the air handler (system is a First Co air handler with hot water boiler for heat and separate condenser for A/C).  I've attached a wiring diagram.  Can I simply splice into the brown wire directly off the transformer without effecting anything else?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Yes, that should work. I'd prefer to make the splice at a terminal or an existing junction, but you can splice it in the middle of the wire just as well (as long as there's enough slack in the wire).

Comment: Thank you.  Based on the diagram, and your comment of a terminal or junction, is there another spot you'd recommend connecting the C wire?

Comment: I'd have to see how the wires are connected at each location, to determine the *best* place to attach a new wire.